Maven Plugin Errors in IntelliJ (Eclipse-based Team) without Modifying POM.xml
I'm working on a Java project where the entire team uses Eclipse. I prefer using IntelliJ IDEA and have cloned the project into it. However, I'm encountering several Maven-related errors in IntelliJ, even though the pom.xml works perfectly fine in Eclipse.
Some of the specific errors are:
Plugin 'org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.11.0.1615' not found
Cannot resolve symbol 'Install4jHome' (This is a pipeline variable)
Plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:3.0' not found
Value must not be empty
The main issue is that I cannot modify the POM.xml since it's shared with the team, and it's working for them in Eclipse.
I've tried refreshing the Maven project, invalidating caches in IntelliJ, and reimporting Maven dependencies, but the errors persist.
Is there a way to resolve these issues in IntelliJ without modifying the POM.xml? Any insights on how to handle IDE-specific Maven configurations, especially when switching from Eclipse to IntelliJ, would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

I prefer using IntelliJ IDEA and have **cloned the project**  into it. <--- File -> Open your maven project.

REmove the maven-eclipse-plugin from your build that plugin is long end of life ... Eclipse as well as IntelliJ can import Maven project natively...
